# bash vi mode: What does # -*- mode: ruby -*- # vi: set ft=ruby : mean?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, emacs, ruby

I'm looking through [some random code](https://github.com/honza/django-chef/blob/master/Vagrantfile), and at the top of it, it says this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
```

What does this mean?

I know it's a simple question, but I couldn't find it out online because a) I don't even know what language this code is written in, and b) I'm very new to bash and vi.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with bash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those lines are modelines which tell an editor (e.g. emacs or vi) to choose a specific editing mode for a file. An editing mode affects how editor e.g. higlights and indents contents of the file.

You can read more about modelines for emacs (which are called file-local variables) [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html) and modelines for vim [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic).

Comment: It's modeline not magical line.

Comment: Actually it's most often called magical modeline where I come from, just to distinguish it from modeline of emacs which is entirely different thing.

Comment: Well, in Vim, it's called "modeline" and in Emacs it's called "file-local variables".

Comment: I suggest an edit then.